# Unable to use firefox v53 using protractor

Tags: selenium, webdriver, protractor, firefox-driver

I am using protractor to run test and firefox is started giving error suddenly.

error:

```
    [14:37:20] E/launcher - Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'trv2457.local', ip: '2001:920:1841:10:5d36:7ac0:12e1:a37c', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.4', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   0:        0x103dc237e - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h76b688ec9dd0c4e2
   1:        0x103dc2abc - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::hb5a725a088a2a2fc
   2:        0x103d7b01b - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler::create_connection::h6c6a5e0bb57aa48d
   3:        0x103d8347f - _$LT$geckodriver..marionette..MarionetteHandler$u20$as$u20$webdriver..server..WebDriverHandler$LT$geckodriver..marionette..GeckoExtensionRoute$GT$$GT$::handle_command::h1551b734f4cde0a0
   4:        0x103d76340 - webdriver::server::start::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h89f46c6cb17a6c48
   5:        0x103d49dcd - std::panicking::try::do_call::h20be620158d9b55a
   6:        0x103eec5ba - __rust_maybe_catch_panic
   7:        0x103d58aea - _$LT$F$u20$as$u20$alloc..boxed..FnBox$LT$A$GT$$GT$::call_box::h4fac0ee9906c8727
   8:        0x103eeaa14 - std::sys::imp::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::hca57ad22492f366f
   9:     0x7fffe3fce9ae - _pthread_body
  10:     0x7fffe3fce8fa - _pthread_start
```

Any idea?

Comment: Update your question with the Protractor, geckodriver version,  are you using the grid to run your tests?

Comment: Hi, Protractor =  5.1.1, gekodriver = 0.16.1. I am using protractor and it uses webdriver

Answer (score 0):

**There were issues with protractor with Firefox v53.0**

(refer https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4253), are now resolved.

Protractor works well with higher versions of Firefox.

1. Upgrade Mozilla Firefox to version > 59.0 (Firefox Quantum)
2. "Use directConnect: true" in the conf.js